# Need to open a file and replace multiple strings

Tags: string, file, perl, replace

I have a really big xml file. It has certain incrementing numbers inside, which i would like to replace with a different incrementing number. I've looked and here is what someone suggested here before. Unfortunately i cant get it to work :(

In the code below all instances of 40960 should be replaced with 41984, all instances of 40961 with 41985 etc. Nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $old = 40960;
my $new = 41984;
my $string;

my $file = 'file.txt';

rename($file, $file.'.bak');
open(IN, '<'.$file.'.bak') or die $!;
open(OUT, '>'.$file) or die $!;

$old++;
$new++;

for (my $i = 0; $i < 42; $i++) {
    while(<IN>) {
        $_ =~ s/$old/$new/g;
        print OUT $_;
    }
}

close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Comment: You may have to seek back to the beginning of the input file for each iteration in the `for` loop, see [perldoc seek](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html). But there might be more efficient approaches that lets you replace all numbers at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers give you better solutions to your problem. Mine concentrates on explaining why your code didn't work.

The core of your code is here:

```
$old++;
$new++;

for (my $i = 0; $i < 42; $i++) {
    while(<IN>) {
        $_ =~ s/$old/$new/g;
        print OUT $_;
    }
}
```

You increment the values of `$old` and `$new` outside of your loops. And you never change those values again. So you're only making the same substitution (changing 40961 to 41985) 42 times. You never try to change any other numbers.

Also, look at the `while` loop that reads from `IN`. On your first iteration (when `$i` is 0) you read all of the data from `IN` and the file pointer is left at the end of the file. So when you go into the `while` loop again on your second iteration (and all subsequent iterations) you read no data at all from the file. You need to reset the file pointer to the start of your file at the end of each iteration.

Oh, and the basic logic is wrong. If you think about it, you'll end up writing each line to the output file 42 times. You need to do all possible substitutions before writing the line. So your inner loop needs to be the outer loop (and vice versa).

Putting those suggestions together, you need something like this:

```
my $old    = 40960;
my $change = 1024;

while (<IN>) {
    # Easier way to write your loop
    for my $i ( 1 .. 42 ) {
        my $new = $old + $change;
        # Use \b to mark word boundaries
        s/\b$old\b/$new/g;
        $old++;
    }
    # Print each output line only once
    print OUT $_;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized myself how i failed with the looping placement, but completely missed the file handle issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that works line by line, so the size of file is immaterial. The example assumes you want to replace things like "45678", but not "fred45678".  The example also assumes that there is a range of numbers, and you want them replaced with a new range offset by a constant.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant MIN => 40000;
use constant MAX => 90000;
use constant DIFF => +1024;

sub repl { $_[0] >= MIN && $_[0] <= MAX ? $_[0] + DIFF : $_[0] }

while (<>) {
    s/\b(\d+)\b/repl($1)/eg;
    print;
}
exit(0);
```

Invoked with the file you want to transform as an argument, it produces altered output on stdout. With the following input ...

```
foo bar 123
40000 50000 60000 99999
fred60000
fred 60000 fred
```

... it produces this output.

```
foo bar 123
41024 51024 61024 99999
fred60000
fred 61024 fred
```

There are a couple of classic Perlisms here, but the example shouldn't be hard to follow if you RTFM appropriately.

Comment: That looks interesting, but also quite complex for a total beginner like me. Could you add a few comments as to what does what?

Comment: repl() is a simple function which, given x, returns x+DIFF if x >= MIN and x <= MAX, or just returns x otherwise. The main while() loop iterates over lines of the incoming file, locates any numeric sequence surrounded by "boundary" conditions (that's the \b part of the regex), replaces those strings with whatever the repl() function returns, and prints the modified line. If a number falls outside the MIN-MAX range, the number is simply substituted with itself, so there is no change.  If the number falls within the MIN-MAX range, however, the substitution replaces the old number with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way which reads the input file into a string and does all the substitutions at once:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
my $old = 40960;
my $new = 41984;

my ($regexp) = map { qr/$_/ } join '|', map { $old + $_ } 0..41;

my $file = 'file.txt';
rename($file, $file.'.bak');
open(IN, '<'.$file.'.bak') or die $!;
my $str = do {local $/; <IN>};
close IN;
$str =~ s/($regexp)/do_subst($1, $old, $new)/ge;

open(OUT, '>'.$file) or die $!;
print OUT $str;
close OUT;

}

sub do_subst {
    my ( $old, $old_base, $new_base ) = @_;
    my $i = $old - $old_base;
    my $new = $new_base + $i;
    return $new;
}
```

Note: Can probably be made more efficient by using [`Regexp::Assemble`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble)

Comment: My xml file is quite big, I wonder if it would cause an issue if converted to a string.